# Is Oozie workflow is supported in spark standalone

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I'm new to workflow engines and I'm in a need of fork a couple of my jobs. So I thought of using *Apache Oozie* for the purpose.I use Spark Standalone as my cluster manager.

But Most of the documents I gone through talks only about oozie on YARN.My question ***"Is Oozie workflow is supported for spark standalone and recommended?"***
if so, can you share an example for the same?  alternatively I would also like to know the possibilities of doing ***fork*** 
in spark without using any of the workflow engines.  What is the industry standard way of scheduling jobs apart from `cron`?

Comment: The whole purpose of Oozie is to schedule Hadoop jobs on a Hadoop cluster. Looks like it's not a good fit for you.

Comment: Okay. do you prefer cron jobs for scheduling ??

Comment: CRON simply runs task, it has no "workflow" feature... There are a couple of Python utilities out there, such as Luigi https://github.com/spotify/luigi or AirFlow https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/ that may be a good fit for you. Or maybe Azkaban https://azkaban.github.io/ but it's probably overkill.